# How to add conditional has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, conditional-associations

I have following DB structure

tasks

```
id   name   parent_id
1    Abc    nil
2    Pqr    1
```

comments

```
id task_id body  
1   1      This is sample comment
2   1      This is another sample comment
```

task.rb

```
has_many :comments
```

comment.rb

```
belongs_to :task
```

My requirement is to have an associations such that for the parent as well as children i should get the parent comments i.e. for both the above tasks i should get ['This is sample comment', 'This is another sample comment'] as child tasks will not have any comments.

I tried something like following but it doesn't work

task.rb

```
has_many :comments,  -> (o) { where(comments: {task_id: [o.id, o.parent_id]}) }
```

Comment: _but it doesn't work_ -- Is there any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because your new condition is combined with the default one that comes from `has_many`. You can use `unscope` method to cancel the default condition:

```
has_many :comments, -> (task) { unscope(:where).where(comments: {task_id: [task.id, task.parent_id]}) }
```

**NOTE**: This will break `default_scope` of the Comment model if there is one.

In Rails5 you would be able to add `OR` condition to the default one:

```
has_many :comments, -> (task) { or(comments: {task_id: task.parent_id}) }
```

Comment: I tried with `rewhere` but it is still combining the default one

Comment: You are right. That did not work. I need more time to find the solution

Comment: Here you go! Updated the answer.

Comment: But it is not working for `Task.where(id: [1,2]).includes(:comments)`

Comment: it throw's error `DEPRECATION WARNING: The association scope 'comments' is instance dependent (the scope block takes an argument). Preloading happens before the individual instances are created. This means that there is no instance being passed to the association scope. This will most likely result in broken or incorrect behavior. Joining, Preloading and eager loading of these associations is deprecated and will be removed in the future.`

Comment: Yes, there is a related problem. Associations like this can't be used for preloading data using `:joins` or `:includes`. There is a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654098/rails-5-how-to-form-association-between-tables-on-multiple-shared-attributes .  It is not solved at the moment I wright this comment, but I hope it will be.